# Forms with out using <form action: MAILTO:>

Tags: php, html, forms

I am creating a website that has a form in the the side bar on all of my pages. How can I make it so when the submit button is clicked and the form information goes to an email without using the action: MAILTO:? I am wondering whether if I can make a separate php page that can do this. What would be the best solution?

Comment: php, `mail()` function

Comment: FYI mailto does not work as a form action

Answer (score 1):

You basically want your form to mail something, instead of popping an email client, right? That requires the script to ask the server to do the mailing. In PHP that would be:

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```